# IQueryable not generating the desired query in entity framework core

Tags: api, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, iqueryable

I have some entities similar to the following:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string CurrentGrade { get; set; }
    public int YearsTeaching { get; set; }
    pubilc ICollection<StudentFeedback> StudentFeedback { get; set; }
}

public class StudentFeedback
    {
        public int StudentFeedBackId { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Feedback { get; set; }

        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
    } 
    
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string CurrentGrade { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository with a method where I want to return a teacher or list of teachers where the StudentFeedback returned belongs to the student who is looking at it (the studentId is stored in a token).

So, lets say I have the Teacher (teacherId) and a Student (userId) who is hitting the API endpoint. I currently have the following:

```
int teacherId = 2;
int userId = 20; // This is the currently logged in user, extracted from the token.

var query = _context.Teachers.AsQueryable();/* _context is the DataContext*/
query = query.Where(t => p.TeacherId == teacherId);
query = query.Where(u => u.StudentFeedback.Any(x => x.StudentId == userId));
```

However this is still returning all StudentFeedback from all Students, so long as the userId (student) has feedback provided for the teacher in question. I had a look at the query that gets executed and the problem is that the studentId predicate is in the wrong place. A very rough version of the query is:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (   SELECT  t.*
                FROM    dbo.Teachers t
                WHERE   (t.TeacherId = 2)
                        AND EXISTS (   SELECT   1
                                       FROM     dbo.StudentFeedback t0
                                       WHERE    (t.TeacherId = t0.TeacherId)
                                                AND (t0.StudentId = 20))) p
LEFT JOIN   dbo.StudentFeedback sf ON p.TeacherId = sf.TeacherId
```

Whereas it should be something like

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (   SELECT  t.*
                FROM    dbo.Teachers t
                WHERE   (t.TeacherId = 2)) p
LEFT JOIN   dbo.StudentFeedback sf ON p.TeacherId = sf.TeacherId
                                      AND   sf.StudentId = 20
```

but I don't know how to make that happen. Is there something wrong with the IQueryable predicates I've setup or have I missed some logic in the modelBuilder within the datacontext?
Thank-you.

Edit: I am using Entity Framework Core 5.0.2 and I am also using Automapper with the following code:

```
query.ProjectTo<TeacherDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).AsNoTracking()
```

Here is what I am getting back currently:

```
[
        {
            "teacherid": 2,
            "teacherName": "Jane Smith",
            "age": 35,
            "currentGrade": "One",
            "yearsTeaching": 12,
            "studentFeedback": [
                {
                    "studentFeedBackId": 12,
                    "teacherId": 6,
                    "studentId": 20,
                    "feedback": "Ms Smith is my favorite teacher"
                } ,
                {
                    "studentFeedBackId": 16,
                    "teacherId": 6,
                    "studentId": 43,
                    "feedback": "Ms Smith was so kind to me"
                } ,
                {
                    "studentFeedBackId": 21,
                    "teacherId": 6,
                    "studentId": 89,
                    "feedback": "Thank you Mrs Smith for being my teacher. I learned a lot."
                } 
            ]
        }
    ]
```

here is what I want to be getting back:

```
[
    {
        "teacherid": 2,
        "teacherName": "Jane Smith",
        "age": 35,
        "currentGrade": "One",
        "yearsTeaching": 12,
        "studentFeedback": [
            {
                "studentFeedBackId": 12,
                "teacherId": 6,
                "studentId": 20,
                "feedback": "Ms Smith is my favorite teacher"
            } 
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I added the EF version. By "returning all StudentFeedback from all users" I mean the StudentFeedback from every Student. I'll update the wording in the question. The second query is definitely what I want. I've run the query directly on the database to get the results I am after.

Comment: I have provided examples of what I am getting back vs what I want to get back

Comment: Hi Gert. I tried ```query = query.Include(u => u.StudentFeedback.Where(x => x.StudentId == userId));``` but I got the exactly the same result but a slightly different query. In this instance there was no EXISTS clause at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @LucianBargaoanu for pointing me in the right direction by saying to have the `where` in the mapping itself. The solution is to use [Parameterization](https://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization) when using Automapper:

The code from this pages shows an example:

```
string currentUserName = null;
cfg.CreateMap<Course, CourseModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.CurrentUserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => currentUserName));
```

and then

```
dbContext.Courses.ProjectTo<CourseModel>(Config, new { currentUserName = Request.User.Name });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a join you should use Join method in your linq statement. See https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-joining-operator-join . You got exactly what you wrote in your query. `Where(u => u.StudentFeedback.Any(x => x.StudentId == userId));`
.Any translates to exists.

Comment: *If you want a join*. Maybe the first question should be: do you really want this join? The join statement should rarely be used in LINQ-to-Entities queries. Navigation properties are there for a reason. *If* the query should return`StudentFeedback` data (which seems opposite to what the question states) `Include` should be used.

Comment: `Include` is not needed with `ProjectTo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Net5 EF you can just add a Students property to the Teacher class:

```
public class Teacher
{
    .....
    pubilc ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    pubilc ICollection<StudentFeedback> StudentFeedbacks { get; set; }
}
```

You can use query this way:

```
var query = _context.Teachers.Include(i=> i.StudentFeedbacks)
.Where(t => 
t.TeacherId == teacherId 
&&  t.StudentFeedbacks.Any(x => x.StudentId == userId))
.ToArray();
```

Comment: You can achieve the same thing without any `Include`, by having the `where` in the mapping itself.

Comment: Hi @LucianBargaoanu How do you can you add the where to the mapping the userId is a variable?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization